# Are these British cavalry uniforms?

Tags: military, uniform

Photo either taken in Durban (Port Natal) or Cornwall, perhaps World War 1
Would a military unit wear jackets that didn't match the jodhpurs?
There is no accompanying information for this photo of my grandfather + 1.
I am trying to establish a time line for my grandfathers move from the UK to South Africa.

[Two men in light colored, four pocket uniform jackets lean on a chair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a7eL.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Certainly, including the [1st Madras Light Cavalry](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/132785888991417583/) and [6th  Inniskilling Dragoons](http://www.uniformology.com/HEAVY-CAVALRY/X-Dragoon_Guards___Dragoons.jpg) for example.

Comment: OP provided picture; question is a candidate for re-open.

Comment: It's hard to say the Woseley Pattern Helmets on the chair were adopted in 1896 by the British military in 1900 it was given the stamp of approval for West African and Chinese regiments and used more broadly starting in 1904. I can't make out the patch either. Also looking at the uniforms in other pictures it seems that lighting can make a big difference and the "color" difference could just be the angle of the light?